# Не отображаются символы emoji в title wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Стоит плагин The SEO Framework и когда в настройках заголовка страницы или описания страницы, ставишь смайлик, после сохранения страницы он просто пропадает из описания или тайтла. Как это поправить?

Comment: А в какой файл базы данных вставлять этот код?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема скорее всего связана с кодировкой вашей таблицы. `utf8_*` не поддерживает некоторые хитрые символи юникода.

Нужно использовать кодировки `utf8mb4_*`

Пример как заменить кодировку в таблицах:

```
# Запустите это один раз для каждой схемы (замените database_name на имя схемы)
ALTER DATABASE database_name CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

# Запустите это один раз для каждой таблицы (замените table_name именем таблицы)
ALTER TABLE table_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

# Выполните это для каждого столбца (замените имя таблицы, column_name, тип столбца, максимальную длину и т. д.)
ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE column_name column_name VARCHAR(191) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Не забудьте в `wp-config.php` заменить константу `DB_CHARSET`